# Kendo Grid filter does not work inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am stuck with this previously asked issue for last one day and now i am totally clueless how to fix it.

[Kendo UI grid filters not working inside a bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201790/kendo-ui-grid-filters-not-working-inside-a-bootstrap-modal)

I have my modal set up like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="gapModalDiv" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog custom-class" role="document">  
<div class="modal-content text-center">
  <div id="gapFocusDiv">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Eligible Person - </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
            .Name("grid")
            .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
            .Excel(excel => excel
                .AllPages(true)
                .FileName("Test.xlsx")
            )
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.Code).Title("Code").Width(150);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.RI).Title("RI").Width(70);
            })
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Filterable()
            .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
               .Ajax()
               .ServerOperation(false)
               .PageSize(20)
           )
      )
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add your code. It'd be better to help if you do.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Turns out when we put the width to each column the calculated width does not match to the total width of the model when kendo tries to paint the grid. Hence to resolve this, add width to the column you want to resize and let the remain column width be auto calculated by the grid.

Hope this helps anyone facing the same issue.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Code).Title("Code").Width(50);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
            columns.Bound(p => p.RI).Title("RI").Width(50);
```